# Getting jQuery error on one site but not the other same exact code

Tags: jquery, html, syntax-error

I've got two websites, https://HowStrongIsMy.PW and https://IsMyPasswordStrong.pw . When I originally launched both of these they worked fine, but one of the sites has recently broken and I have not added or changed anything since launch.

The errors I get are:

```
jQuery is not defined
```

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: Why are use `data-rocketsrc` use only `src` attribute  eg `<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/rocketscript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>`

Comment: This error is generally thrown when file is not loaded or someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable

Comment: @TamilSelvan I'll change it and see if that fixes it, any other suggestion?